# How to write surface Function for Shape - Circle with decleration of data-type Radius?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

The Haskell code below works fine.

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Shape = Circle Point Float  
surface :: Shape -> Float  
surface (Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2
```

Result:

```
*Main> surface $ Circle (Point 0 0) 10  
314.15927
```

The Haskell code below does not work. Why? How to write surface function for `Shape` - `Circle` correctly?

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Radius = Radius Float deriving (Show)

data Shape = Circle Point Radius   

surface :: Shape -> Float  
surface (Circle _ (Radius r)) = pi * (Radius r) ^ 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is constructing a `Radius` object and raising that to a power. Since you haven’t defined the power operator for `Radius`, that can’t work. Remove the constructor call:

```
surface (Circle _ (Radius r)) = pi * r ^ 2
```

Comment: Konrad Rudolph: Sir, Remove the constructor call means, I have to write data Shape = Circle Point Float , right? Which will be better writing a power operator for Radius or removing the constructor call? How to write power operator for Radius? Please guide.

Comment: @Optimight No, it doesn’t mean that; look at my code, the `Circle` class is still built with a `Radius`. Only the calculation itself works on `float` directly

Comment: Sir, Got the point. Your suggested code compiles, OK. But When I run it and try to test it with : (a)  surface $ Circle (Point 0 0) 1      (b)  surface $ Circle ((Point 0 0) 10) and (c) surface $ Circle ((Point 0 0) Radius 10) - All fails. Unable to understand the respective error message and implement accordingly. Please guide.

Comment: @Optimight It should be `surface $ Circle (Point 0 0) (Radius 10)`

Answer (score 1):

There's two fixes. One is the just like the first snippet of code you wrote: use a `Float` instead of a `Radius` in the actual calculation bit.

```
surface :: Shape -> Float
surface (Circle _ (Radius r)) = pi * r ^ 2
```

The other is to look at the type of `(^)`:

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) -> a -> b -> a
```

...and observe that for `Radius r ^ 2` to work, we would need to have an instance `Num Radius`. Also, the result would be a value of type `Radius` (not `Float`), so the type signature of `surface` would have to change to match. Easy:

```
newtype Radius = Radius Float deriving (Num, Show)

surface :: Shape -> Radius -- weird looking type
surface (Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2
surface (Circle _ (Radius r)) = pi * Radius r ^ 2 -- equivalent
```

Comment: Don't you have to turn `Radius` into a `newtype` for `deriving Num` to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `(,)` instead of `Point`, and `Float` instead of `Radius`.

You can also define the `Shape` as a class. So the code will be

```
type Point = (Float, Float)
data Circle = Circle { center :: Point, radius :: Float }

class Shape a where
  surface :: a -> Float

instance Shape Circle where
  surface c = pi * (radius c) ** 2
```

This is a possible implementation, just try it ~